# Isomorphic vector bundles have same characteristic classes

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes, natural-transformations

Following is an excerpt from the book "Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes" that defines naturality of characteristic classes.

[image]

My question is how does naturality property imply "isomorphic vector bundles have same characteristic classes".

Edit: I think I got it now. Is it correct?
[image]

Comment: It doesn't; it's implied by the fact that $\text{Vect}_k$ is defined to be the set of isomorphism classes of vector bundles. (This is a little awkward and there are less tautological ways to do this.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. But then I do not see that characteristic classes are well defined i.e. why the cohomology classes  $[P(\Omega)]$ are isomorphism invariant?